flutter background location access when app is killed and internet is off
hello i am trying to add location feature in Flutter android

get user coordiantes when application is killed
it should work even with no internet connection

i found many solution but still confused and searching for best one, is there any best solution? want to find optimal solution for my problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
